# Upload a file with AJAX, Python, and CGI

Tags: python, php, ajax, cgi

I'm using AJAX to post uploaded file to python cgi, but I'm not sure how to handle the uploaded file in cgi.

here's my js code:

```
function ajaxupload(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fm = new FormData();
    var file_obj = document.getElementById('file').files[0]
    console.log(file_obj)
    fm.append('file',file_obj)
    xhr.open('POST','/cgi-bin/UploadFile.py',true);
    xhr.send(fm)
}
```

here's my python code:

```
import cgi, os
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem = form['filename']
os.system("cp fileitem ")
```

The file can be uploaded successfully.
I want to save the file to a folder on server, but there's no documentation about it.

Comment: `fileitem` should be special object which you should use to get data and save it with `open()` `write()` `close()`.

Comment: if you want to use value from variable inside string then you should use `string formatting` like `"cp {}".format(fileitem)` or `f-string` like `f"cp {fileitem}"` or old method with `%` like `"cp %s" % fileitem`. See page https://pyformat.info/